# Use gamma distribution or log-transform with OLS?

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, gamma-distribution

I have blood levels of a chemical as the response or dependent variable. The minimum can be 0 and it has distribution as shown in figure below:

[image]

I believe this is a [gamma distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution).

I have to perform regression with many categorical and continuous variables. What will be best method to proceed:

1. To apply some transformation (e.g. log) to convert above to a more normal distribution and apply OLS.
2. To use Generalized Linear Model (GLM) specifying family as Gamma as shown [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/glm.html?highlight=gamma#GLM:-Gamma-for-proportional-count-response).

Or some other method is more suitable for above situation?

**Edit:** My main aim of regression is to identify variables which have an independent association with blood levels of this chemical.

Comment: What might be 'best' depends on all manner of things. What are you using the model to do? Why would looking at the marginal response be any use in choosing a model? What makes you think the conditional distribution is gamma?

Comment: I have added aim of regression in my question above. Secondly, I am not able to understand your comment: "conditional distribution is gamma" in relation to multiple regression

Comment: You are looking at a histogram of the response mixed across all the values of the predictors (the marginal distribution of the response) and assert that it's gamma. No assumption of GLMs relates to the distribution of the response by itself like that. Instead GLMs are a model for the *conditional* distribution.  If you're contemplating a gamma GLM, why are you looking at - and asserting something about - the marginal distribution of the response?

Comment: When we make an assumption of normality in OLS regression, that assumption is about the error term (related to the conditional distribution), not about the pooled distribution of all observations of the response variable.

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I realize that there is no assumption of normality on either dependent or independent variables in linear regression. The normality assumption is only for error terms or residuals.

Comment: @Dave : It is mentioned here by 2 writers that using gamma distribution may be better with such data: from: https://www.researchgate.net/post/When_and_in_what_situation_gamma_GLM_is_recommended

Comment: This interesting article states OLS may be as good as GLM with gamma: https://pj.freefaculty.org/guides/stat/Regression-GLM/Gamma/GammaGLM-01.pdf